Вывод сложной геометрии в Python
Мне нужно вывести сложную кривую в Python, такую как на изображение: 
Я не знаю какие инструменты можно использовать и какие методы позволят это сделать. Подскажите примеры реализации и наиболее оптимальные методы для данной задачи (возможно стоит использовать matplotlib или возможности PyQt?)

matplotlib вполне подойдёт. pyqt - это скорее про пользовательский интерфейс, нежели про отрисовку.

А в чём именно у вас сложность? Все элементы по отдельности можно нарисовать, не вопрос. Читайте доку по matplotlib.

@CrazyElf сложность в том, что перемене разных частей происходит в разных точках, которые задаются пользователем. И то есть код должен корректно работать во всех случаях
